# How to select irregular shapes in a image

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation

Using python code we are able to create image segments as shown in the screenshot. our requirement is **how to select specific segment in the image and apply different color to it ?**

[image]

The following is our python snippet

```
from skimage.segmentation import felzenszwalb, slic,quickshift

from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries

from skimage.util import img_as_float

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import measure

from skimage import restoration

from skimage import img_as_float

image = img_as_float(io.imread("leaf.jpg"))
segments = quickshift(image, ratio=1.0, kernel_size=20, max_dist=10,return_tree=False, sigma=0, convert2lab=True, random_seed=42)

fig = plt.figure("Superpixels -- %d segments" % (500))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(image, segments))

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
seg_num = 64 # desired segment to be colored
color = float64([1,0,0]) # red color
image[segments == 64] = color # assign color to the segment
```

Comment: Thanks buddy u solved my problem... small change.                                  color = np.float64([1,0,0])

Comment: small help,based on the mouse click how to update the color in the specific segment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenCV python module - example](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/10/20/finding-shapes-images-using-python-opencv/):